# Windows 8: File Dialog Missing File Names

Tags: windows-8

In any application, if I do File > Open or Save As or pretty much anything that opens a file browser type dialog, the file names are missing.  Any view (list, details, thumbnails, etc) and any sort order.  All I see are the icons for the files and folders, and if I click on one of them, the file name shows in the file name text box.

I did a clean install of Windows 8 Pro and I'm pretty sure this was happening from the beginning, but I can't be sure.  I did install several programs before I noticed... Office 2010, Firefox, etc.

This screenshot is the Open dialog in Word 2010, but it doesn't matter which program I use, they all look like this:
[image: Missing Filenames]

UPDATE: I decided to add another screenshot and noticed that the same behavior does NOT occur in Win8's Paint!!

[image: Save As dialog in Firefox]

Comment: Does this happen with drives other than C, too?

Comment: Yes.  In fact, the drive list is blank, too.  :)

Comment: No name shows up even when you select/highlight a file/folder? What about changing the view - do the names show up in Details view for example?

Comment: Same behavior when selecting a file and changing view.  While adding this screenshot, however, I noticed that Paint does not have the problem.  It's the only thing I've found unaffected so far.  Could it be something particular to .NET versions prior to 4...?

Comment: @MichaelNelson: First, try changing the theme by right-clicking the desktop and choosing *Personalize* in case the current one is somehow corrupt. But my guess is that it could be down to faulty graphics card drivers, so try updating if possible.

Comment: Changing the theme did not help.  I'm going to upgrade video cards in the next few days anyway (which of course will involve installing a new driver) and will report back.

Comment: Replaced video card and driver, no help.  :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this option?

Go to

> Folder Options -> View

and then select

> "Show drive letters"

Hope this helps.

Comment: Have you tried that yourself?

Comment: Yes, I deselected it and the drive letters was not show.
I could not post a screen shot as I did not have enough reputation! :D

Comment: The question that you have answered is about missing file names not missing drive letters, does showing drive letters cause the missing file names to show?

Comment: If you don't have enough reputation to put a screenshot in, upload it to http://imgur.com/ and post a link to it, someone with higher reputation will edit it for you

Comment: If you look at his screenshot even the drive letters are missing. Hence it might be well worth a try even though I tried it with windows 7.

Comment: It was already checked.  I tried unchecking and rechecking, no help.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Try safe boot option explained here - http://www.howtogeek.com/107511/how-to-boot-into-safe-mode-on-windows-8-the-easy-way/